# What characteristics define something as a mathematical entity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, definitions

It is easy to give examples of mathematical entities: Natural numbers, geometrical figures, sets, functions of variables ranging over numerical sets, etc. The list seems endless. Yet, listing those entities which are objects of known mathematical theorems would presumably not do justice to the mathematical idea of mathematical entity.

So, *what characteristics if any truly qualify something as a mathematical entity?*

Thanks for scholarly references.

Comment: Charles Parsons, [Mathematical Thought and its Objects (Cambridge UP, 2008)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Thought_and_its_Objects/C1r-9C8yP34C)

Comment: That is a lovely question. One that is easy to understand, demands no specialist knowledge, and requires nothing but time to think.

Comment: None. Mathematical entities are placeholders in mathematical structures, that is systems described precisely enough to allow proving claims about them deductively. Their characteristics as entities are orthogonal to what makes them mathematical, namely, the formality of description. Any abstract entity can be made mathematical by formalizing it (in modern approximation, defining it in ZFC). Already Aristotle points towards such operational view of mathematics, see [Cadavid, Existence in a way: resolving a tension in Aristotle’s philosophy of mathematics](http://hdl.handle.net/1802/9552).

Comment: See Quine “Any progression will serve as a version of number so long as and only so long as we stick to one and the same progression. Arithmetic is, in this sense, all there is to number: there is no saying absolutely what the numbers are; there is only rithmetic” (*Ontological Relativity*, 1968).

Comment: Where did you get the idea listing those entities which are objects of known mathematical theorems would not do justice to the mathematical idea of mathematical entity?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Where from do you get the idea that it would?

Comment: "*None. Mathematical entities are placeholders in mathematical structures*" Ah, good! So, the characteristic, the only characteristic, of mathematical entities, is that they are *placeholders in mathematical structures*. Thanks. Why did you say "*none*", though?

Comment: I would say a mathematical entity is anything  expressable in one of the formal languages of mathematics.

Comment: @Speakpigeon  I got the idea from reading your exposition, partly because of the unsupported use of 'presumably'… I think Conifold said 'None…' because the Question was 'What characteristics…'

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*the unsupported use of 'presumably'*" Presumably just means capable of being presumed or taken for granted. Reasonable as a supposition. I was asking a question, not writing a dissertation. - 2. "*I got the idea from reading your exposition*" So it is no more *supported* than my own. - 3. "*I think Conifold said 'None…'*" Sure, and other people offered what are in effect what they themselves presume are characteristics of mathematical entities. So, I was correct in presuming.

Comment: I hope you don't really believe that definition of 'presumably.' In the context you used, 'presumably' actually means 'presumed by me…' Of course my query is 'no more supported' than yours; it's a query, not an argument. Don't you see the difference?
I suggest no-one doubts Conifold's 'None…' was a clear Answer to your 'what characteristics… '

I suggest '… what they themselves presume…' again shows how perverse your idea of 'presumably' is.

Sorry you feel so combative.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*actually means 'presumed by me*" Actually? No, sorry, this is very naïve. Sentences don't *actually* mean anything by themselves. We do. So here I'm the only one who decides what *I mean* by what I say. All you can do is decide for yourself what you understand by what I say, but then it is your responsibility, not mine. Further, I used the definition provided by dictionaries. Your interpretation is parochial.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*Don't you see the difference?*" There is a difference. Your idea that my "presumably" means "*presumed by me*" cannot be supported, while my use of "presumably" is supported by several of the answers offered to my question.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*I suggest no-one doubts Conifold's 'None…' was a clear Answer to your 'what characteristics… '*" So what? His comment is just as clearly not shared by many and perhaps most people, and not even clearly correct, as demonstrated by my reply.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*I suggest '… what they themselves presume…' again shows how perverse your idea of 'presumably' is. *" Sorry, I've no idea what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "*Sorry you feel so combative.*" Why do you feel sorry? Saying someone is combative is usually meant as a compliment! English doesn't seem to be your native language. I objected to your comment because it was wrong. If you cannot stand your comments being objected to, don't make absurd comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a real definition of mathematical entity that goes beyond a general purpose dictionary, then you are engaged in one of the central question of the [philosophy of mathematics (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/). Generally, mathematical entities are taken to possess the characteristics of abstract objects (SEP). From SEP:

> One doesn’t go far in the study of what there is without encountering the view that every entity falls into one of two categories: concrete or abstract. The distinction is supposed to be of fundamental significance for metaphysics (especially for ontology), epistemology, and the philosophy of the formal sciences (especially for the philosophy of mathematics);

In particular, mathematical abstract objects are marked by a number of characteristics that form the basis for claims about their philosophical basis. An accessible book talking about what constitutes mathematical entities is [Linnebo's *Philosophy of Mathematics* (GB)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Mathematics/5yCyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). A look at the table of contents includes some clues of various perspectives. According to famous thinkers, mathematical entities:

1. Have [logical foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicism)
2. Have [numerosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_cognition)
3. [Arise from intuition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism)
4. Possess [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure)
5. Are [conveyed by language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalism)
6. Are [formal but have meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics))
7. Can be related to [empirical experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-empirical_method)

A simple example, like the triangle, can help to make this clear:

1. We can reason about triangles according to Euclid's axioms, for instance.
2. A triangle has three, straight sides.
3. We intuitively grasp that some shapes are triangle-like, for instance, even a shape where the three sides are slightly curved. We can intuit a triangle has three sides and count to three.
4. Triangles can be represented by sets of ordered pairs, or matrices if we prefer.
5. We can talk at length about triangles, and recognize that triangles exist in some sense independent of the physical world.
6. We can use formalisms like taxonomies of triangles and discuss the theory of triangles, trigonometry as a metatheory.
7. Triangles are useful in that they are used in building trusses and pyramids and all manner of things in the physical world.

Comment: "*Have logical foundations*" Presumably, this means that they cannot have mutually contradictory characteristics, yes? - 2. Don't all the characteristics listed in your answer apply to abstract entities in general, including ones which are not considered by mathematicians?

Comment: @Speakpigeon The relationship between logic and mathematical systems can be complicated. Brouwer, the father of rejected two classical laws of logic in his mathematics when he developed [intuitionistic logic (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/). But to simplify, generally numbers and shapes don't have contradictory properties. Circles aren't squares, primes aren't composites. The second question is quite interesting.

Comment: I would suggest that mathematical structure is understood as being capable of describing all abstract objects, in some way or another. A schematic for an electric circuit composed of transistors can have a mathematical description in Boolean logic. A architectural plan is composed of geometric shapes and arithmetic measurements. Zipf's Law can be applied to natural language corpora. If you read the SEP article Abstract Object, you'll see that there's no standard way of visiting it. My preferred way of demarcating mathematical objects as distinct from a more general class:

Comment: Mathematical objects are fictions that are intuitively constructed regarding experiences of quantities, collections, shapes, relations, operations, directions, and truth values. But YMMV with my schema.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental characteristic of a mathematical entity is the requirement of *non-contradiction*.  If there is a contradiction built in, the entity will never fly as a mathematical one.  Such a requirement applies far broader than "an entity in an axiomatic system" because the latter is a fairly modern idea, whereas the principle of non-contradiction was already viewed as a *sine qua non* of a mathematical entity by Leibniz.  Here *non-contradiction* did not necessarily mean to Leibniz that some objectification can be found for the entity in physical reality.  On the contrary, Leibniz emphasized a distinction between absolute impossibility (equivalent to contradiction) and accidental impossibility (something not found in the physical realm but nonetheless useful as a tool in mathematics).  Examples of the latter category to Leibniz are negatives, imaginary roots, and infinitesimals (as well as their inverses: infinite quantities).  For a detailed study of Leibniz's take on mathematical entities, see our recent article

> Katz, M.; Kuhlemann, K.; Sherry, D.; Ugaglia, M. "Leibniz on bodies and infinities: rerum natura and mathematical fictions." Review of Symbolic Logic 17 (2024), no. 1. https://doi.org/10.1017/S1755020321000575, https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.08155

Comment: "_The fundamental characteristic of a mathematical entity is the requirement of non-contradiction_": wrong, _logic_ is the ruleset that determines consistency (ergo, contradictions). Mathematical objects are sustained on logic, but they are not the same.

Comment: @RodolfoAP, I think you may have missed my point.  The Leibnizian principle of non-contradiction was developed long before logic existed as a separate discipline (though Leibniz's genius may have contributed to its eventual creation).  Arguably, the principle of non-contradiction is more basic than any talk about logic as a foundation for mathematics (a view that may not even have been Leibniz's, though it is a common view today).

Comment: @MikhailKatz "*the requirement of non-contradiction*" If contradictory attributes be assigned to a concept, I say, that mathematically the concept does not exist. So, for example, a real number whose square is -l does not exist mathematically. But if it can be proved that the attributes assigned to the concept can never lead to a contradiction by the application of a finite number of logical processes, I say that the mathematical existence of the concept (for example, of a number or a function which satisfies certain conditions) is thereby proved -- David Hilbert, 1900 Lecture in Paris

Comment: @Speakpigeon, Did I say anything to contradict any of the above?  Note that there is a current debate in Leibniz scholarship where one side claims that Leibnizian infinitesimals were contradictory but he managed to use them nonetheless, and the other side says that they were non-contradictory (YHS).  So this is not as obvious as it sounds (at least not to everybody).

Comment: @MikhailKatz "*Did I say anything to contradict any of the above?*" Lol. Not in the least. I put the Hilbert quote to show that he would probably have agreed with your answer . . .  - 2. "*there is a current debate*" Would you have a reference? - 3. "*this is not as obvious as it sounds*" Which was one of Hilbert's points in discussing contradictions which are not obvious in axiom systems.

Comment: @MikhailKatz "*The fundamental characteristic of a mathematical entity is the requirement of non-contradiction.*" I have to agree, so this counts as one characteristic, but this is probably not a specificity of mathematical entities. Any meaningful concept presumably has to be defined non-contradictorily. Games have rules and we don't want them to be mutually contradictory, but a game is not a branch of mathematics.

Comment: @MikhailKatz See Chris Degnen's answer, which I think complete yours.

Comment: The problem is that contradictions aren't "built in" into mathematical objects. Contradictions arise from a surrounding axiomatic framework with rules of inference. Something is only contradictory within some formal framework- necessarily the formal framework is more fundamental than non-contradiction.

Comment: Besides, as a working definition this idea of requiring consistency - merely says what math isn't rather than what is is. We  cannot verify that our notions of mathematics are consistent, as Gödel showed us. Consistent Systems of sufficient strength cannot produce a proof of their own consistency  i.e. They are incomplete

Comment: @Speakpigeon by that standard no object is a mathematical object. We cannot prove that a mathematical idea does not lead to a contradiction. ( Even if we had such a proof, contradictory ideas can prove anything, even their own consistency, so - such a proof wouldn't be definitive) For example, we cannot prove that the Natural Numbers are a consistent construction. By, such a high standard the number 4 isn't a  mathematical object.

Comment: @Speakpigeon. "2. 'there is a current debate' Would you have a reference?" Yes, there is a summary at https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/depictions.html

Comment: @MichaelCarey, I don't think Leibniz meant to claim that one can delineate precisely which the noncontradictory notions are.  He is merely claiming that if a notion has been shown to be contradictory, then one can no longer use it anymore.  Both Leibniz and Hilbert were aware of the fact that catching a contradiction lurking in the background could be very tricky and is not necessarily obvious.  I don't  think Goedel's incompleteness results are that relevant here, even though it obviously was and remains a fabulous accomplishment.  To take a realistic example: if a certain large cardinal ...

Comment: ... hypothesis is proven to be contradictory, this does not mean that all of modern mathematics therefore collapses.  It just means that we don't use that particular hypothesis, in an ardent hope that the rest of set theory will not follow suit :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz ah, I understand. And I would agree with that, at least with respect to a fixed framework. I was just trying to emphasize that "one cannot use it anymore" only refers to a particular framework, not that the object can't find use elsewhere. So, a contradictory large cardinal may be contradictory with ZFC, but not ZF. And so, it is still in some sense perhaps, a "legitimate mathematical object" from the perspective of ZF, but not ZFC.

Comment: I do want to emphasize, that I believe leibniz was correct- contradictions are unsuitable mathematical objects. Maybe, some future clever mathematician will find use for them- but, at least for now they seem entirely worthless. My comment about Gödel, was meant to be in reference to an earlier comment that suggested only provably consistent constructions be legitimate mathematical objects, its not in reference to the Leibnitz point

Comment: @MichaelCarey "*Something is only contradictory within some formal framework*" Sorry but it seems to me that the only "*framework*" which is possibly relevant to decide that something is a contradiction is logic itself. The contradiction may involve more than two elements in a theory, but what matters is that the theory will be inconsistent for containing a contradiction. Remove even one element in the theory to remove the contradiction and it is no longer the same theory. In other word, we are only really interested in theories.

Comment: @MichaelCarey  "*as Gödel showed us*" Sorry, I don't see Gödel's proof as conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a mathematical entity is an idea, not a physical thing.

Secondly, a mathematical idea is an undefinded fundamental concept within an axiomatized theory or it has a precise definition within the theory.

As an example, “set” is an undefined fundamental concept of set theory, while the “intersection of two sets” is defined within set theory. The relation between the undefined fundamental concepts and the definitions within a formalized theory is fixed by the axioms of the theory. Introducing new mathematical concepts into a theory should be consistent with the concepts already at hand.

The examples of the entity “set” or more specific concepts like “topological space”, “topos”, “scheme” show that there is nearly no restriction of the content of a mathematical entity.

Comment: "*a mathematical entity is an idea*" Quine objected. - 2. "*a mathematical idea is an undefinded . . . concept within an axiomatized theory*"  So not really "*within*" the theory. - 3. "*“set” is an undefined . . . concept of set theory, while the “intersection of two sets” is defined within set theory*" How can the notion of the intersection be properly defined in the theory if the notion of set itself isn't? We don't care what we are talking about? We don't know? Mathematical theories perhaps are not self-sufficient? - 4. "*there is nearly no restriction*" What, anything could be?

Comment: @Speakpigeon 1. How does Quine object, can you name a precise reference? 2. Of course is the concept "set" a concept within(!) set theory. 3. "intersection" is defined relatively to the undefined fundamental concepts "set" and "element".

Comment: In *On what there is*, Quine discusses the case of Pegasus and of the Parthenon and explains that we shouldn't confuse the thing and our idea of it. - 2. "*the concept "set" a concept within(!) set theory*" Ok, so it is a meaningless concept *within the theory*. - 3. "*"intersection" is defined relatively to the undefined . . . concepts "set" and "element"*" Ok, so it is also a meaningless concept *within the theory*. Thanks.

Comment: IMO Quine confirms that some ideas have a referent and others do not: Pegasus is an idea without referent. The issue is not "idea versus no idea" but "referent versus no referent". Many mathematical concepts do not have a referent, see my examples.

Comment: "*Quine confirms that some ideas have a referent*" Of course and this is not the debate. My point was that Quine would have objected to your claim that a mathematical entity is an idea. If a geometrical figure for example is a mathematical entity, then a triangle is a mathematical entity, while the idea of the triangle is not. - 2. "* The issue is not "idea versus no idea"*" Don't be silly. This is not what I said. - 3. "*Many mathematical concepts do not have a referent, see my examples.*" Where?

Comment: @Speakpigeon I remember from a previous discussion that we agreed to not agree with each other :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few quotes from *Modern Science, Metaphysics, and Mathematics* by Heidegger regarding mathematics. (36 pages, Internet Archive)

> We attain this fundamental feature of modern science for which we are
> searching by saying that modern science is *mathematical.* ([page
> 249](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n1/mode/1up))

> Therefore, we must now show in what sense the foundation of modern
> thought and knowledge is essentially mathematical. ([page
> 254](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n4/mode/1up))

> The mathematical project of Newtonian bodies leads to the development
> of a certain "mathematics" in the narrow sense. The new form of modern
> science did not arise because mathematics became an essential
> determinant. Rather, that mathematics, and a particular kind of
> mathematics, could come into play and had to come into play is a
> *consequence* of the mathematical project. The founding of analytical
> geometry by Descartes, the founding of the infinitesimal calculus by
> Newton, the simultaneous founding of the differential calculus by
> Leibniz—all these novelties, this mathematical in a narrower sense,
> first became possible and above all necessary on the grounds of the
> basically mathematical character of the thinking. ([page
> 269](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n11/mode/1up))

> In the essence of the mathematical, as the project we delineated, lies
> a specific will to a new formation and self-grounding of the form of
> knowledge as such. ([page
> 272](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n13/mode/1up))

Comment: Where does Heidegger now unveil what "the mathematical character of thinking" is?

Comment: @JoWehler Maybe in the discussion of Descartes on [page 275](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n14/mode/1up) : "all this happened in the midst of a period in which, for a century, mathematics had already been emerging more and more as the foundation of thought and was pressing toward clarity."  . . . "this means that the mathematical wills to ground itself in the sense of its own inner requirements. It expressly intends to explicate itself as the standard of *all* thought and to establish the rules which thereby arise."

Comment: I cannot become friends with Heidegger. I see him only beating around the bush. How much did he understand how mathematics works?

Comment: @JoWehler He seems to start mainly from the axioms of Descartes' *Regulae ad directionem ingenii* (Rules for the Direction of the Mind) and the [*Mathesis universalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathesis_universalis).  This wider sense of mathematics makes sense in the context of Penrose's math-matter-mind triangle, with maths as formal knowledge.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen How is that an answer to my question? - 2. "*modern science is mathematical*" So no science is "*modern*" if it is not mathematised? Isn't *mathematisation* rather just a possible stage in the development of a science? Perhaps even one which is not always possible?

Comment: Indeed he *is* saying 'modern' means mathematical, as observed on [page 271](https://archive.org/details/MartinHeideggerNaturalScienceAndMetaphysics/page/n12/mode/1up) : "Up to the distinct emergence of the mathematical as a fundamental characteristic of thought, the authoritative truth was considered that of Church and faith. The means for the proper knowledge of beings were obtained by way of the interpretation of the sources of revelation, the writ and the tradition of the Church."